# Display input from multimeter on PC

Tags: pcb, circuit-analysis, lcd, multimeter

[image][image]I have opened a Multimeter (Model:DT830D) and I want to take the input that is fed to the LCD display and display it on my PC instead using the serial monitor of the arduino.

But I am confused about the pins which are responsible for sending the measurement values to the LCD display. Because once I find out which pins/circuit wires are responsible for sending for sending the data, I can very easily feed the same to arduino.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the opened meter so that people can get an idea of the type of LCD display used?

Comment: You appear to be talking about the signals between the multimeter's chipset and the **LCD driver**, those signals usually are "standard logic" signals which you can feed to an Arduino. But if the chipset **directly** controls the LCD the LCD driver will be inside the chipset. The signals going to the LCD will be very different from logic signals as they control the **LCD segments directly** and might be more like analog signals.  Just googling DT830D meters: OK, a very cheap meter and ICl7106 based, it has the driver on the chip itself. So what you want will be **very difficult**.

Comment: @crj11 I have updated the pic

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I have updated the pic. Can u check it once and say whether it is possible.

Comment: If you want something to *use* you'd do best doing a web search for either a project of this sort that someone has already worked out for a particular meter (ages ago someone found certain fluke models had *ultrasonic* output that indicated the activated segments), or buying a meter with a data output, or buying or building some kind of data logging system.  Depending on what you want to measure an MCU board (even an Arduino) might work *instead of a meter*, by itself or with an add-on like an INA219 for measuring currents.

Comment: I'm not saying that it is not possible. I am saying that it will be **very difficult**. Because: no logic signals (do research on how LCDs must be used) and not numbers but **segments** of the LCD are switched on/off. So you might need extra electronics to properly translate the signals to Arduino levels. You cannot make such electronics without an **oscilloscope**. You need to write a program to translate segment data back to numbers.

Comment: While if you want to hack this *for the process* get a scope on those nice QFP pads and see what is going on.   LCD signals tend to be bipolar, but sometimes it's all done with a DC offset and the AC is in the phasing between the row and column lines.  There may be MCUs fast enough to capture the row and column outputs and decode it, but you might need to run at a low voltage or use a low threshold buffer.

Comment: Note that LCD segments are controlled with an AC signal. That which you see as 'on' is in fact a (probably square) wave. The vibrating crystals is what you perceive as 'dark'.  If this is a 'fun' project: fine. Otherwise I would no bother.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I will try to get the readings done using scope.

Comment: A segment that is "on" will be a square wave driven in the opposite phase form the column than is currently being driven; a segment that is "off" will be one driven in the same phase as the current column, so you need a two channel scope or at least one triggered on the active column, and then you look at the phase of the segment.

Comment: Why are you looking at the display at all? I'd just try to pull off of the ADC (IC2?). That might be integrated into the COB though, in which case you could try pulling the analog value. Would probably be easier than decoding a 7 segment display.

Comment: @yhyrcanus that's a good idea. Could you help me out with the provided circuit pic and tell me how to do it, in a bit more detail. The chip on board is ICL706, and as u can see it's pretty tough to figure out which pin corresponds to which.

Comment: If you have a scope, look at the pins on IC2 (pins 5/6/7?) and see if its anything you can recognize. If it's some sort of serial data (SPI/I2S), you win, just eat that up with a micro. If not, making your own mutlimeter is probably easier.

Comment: Look at the data sheet for the 7106 and you'll see that it's a static drive LCD with segment signals either in phase or out of phase with the COM signal. So it's possible to decode the segment signals after converting them to logic levels, but the lack of proper *galvanic isolation* means that the multimeter would be pretty useless and/or dangerous to your life and property. Get a DMM with isolated  RS-232 , BT or similar interface.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a multimeter equipped with an isolated serial interface for that purpose. The isolation of the serial interface is important to avoid unwanted grounding of the multimeter circuit.

If you use the multimeter with a connection from the LCD to the PC to measure the power grid voltage (110 or 230 V AC), you may get an electrical shock and destroy the multimeter or the PC or even both.

Using the serial interface for data transfer is easy (been there, done that, but having a good knowledge of asynchronous serial data transmission). Using the LCD signals would be very tricky and difficult.

Comment: could you please give me a bit more detail about your answer. By the tips I am given in the comment section, I definitely understand one thing that I should not try pulling up the values from the LCD signals. Anyways, my main motto is to get the measurement taken by multimeter, and display it in PC.

Comment: @SachinKumar The easiest way would be the use of a multimeter already equipped with a PC interface, may be USB or USART.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But the multimeters with a PC interface facility are very costly (Googled them), and since my budget is not too high, I would prefer taking a normal multimeter and getting the measurements from them, to display on PC.

Comment: @SachinKumar May be you find cheaper data loggers with PC interface.